# Pivot aggregates in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find a way to pivot the table below (I guess you would say it's in "long" format) into the ("wider") format where all the columns are essentially explicitly Boolean. I hope this simple example gets across what I'm trying to do.

Note there is about *74 people.* (so the output table will have 223 columns, 1 + 74 x 3 )

I can't figure out an easy way to do it other than *horribly* with a huge number of left joins along "Town" by statements like

```
... left join(
select 
   town, 
   case where person = 'Richard' then 1 else 0 end as "Richard"
   Fee as "Richard Fee"
from services 
where person = 'Richard'
left join...
```

can some smart person suggest a way to do this using PIVOT functions in SQL?
I am using Snowflake (and dbt so I can get some jinja into play if really necessary to loop through all the people).

Input:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

ps. I know this is a ridiculous SQL ask, but this is the "output the client wants" so I have this undesirable task to fulfil.

Comment: For truly "dynamic" solution, you could use stored procedure [Dynamic PIVOTs in SQL with Snowflake by Felipe Hoffa](https://medium.com/snowflake/dynamic-pivots-in-sql-with-snowflake-c763933987c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If persons are known in advance then you could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT town,
       MAX(CASE WHEN person = 'Richard' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS "Richard",
       MAX(CASE WHEN person = 'Richard' THEN Fee END)       AS "Richard Fee",
       MAX(CASE WHEN person = 'Richard' THEN Service END)   AS "Richard Service",
       MAX(CASE WHEN person = 'Caitlin' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS "Caitlin",
       ...
FROM services 
GROUP BY town;
```

Comment: What is the Max doing - especially when it's a string like Service?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull When you use `GROUP BY town` other columns have to be wrapped with agg function. The values per town are either NULL or values for specific person and MAX allow to get specific value

Comment: this was the smart thing I was missing.

Amazing. 4D chess move right there.

thanks mate

Comment: when I run it in dbt I'm getting the following error for MAX

Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
100038 (22018): Numeric value 'fwa' is not recognized

do you know if there's an equivalent for stings?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull When CASE is used all parts shoulds  be the similar data type. It seems you have something like `MAX(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE col_name END)` and there is implicit conversion to numeric(value "fwa") which fails.